# Python- How to Index and Print More Efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm still in the learning process of Python, and I had a quick question regarding efficiency and readability of my code.

Currently I have this,

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('Data\\cmd.csv')


df=df[['A71: ','A120: ',\
'A70: ','A84: ','A81: ','A89: ',\
'A101: ','A102: ','A105: ','CR']]

X=np.array(df[['A71: ','A120: ',\
'A70: ','A84: ','A81: ','A89: ',\
'A101: ','A102: ','A105: ']])

y=np.array(df[['CR']])

clf=Lasso()
clf.fit(X,y)


print('A71: ', clf.coef_[0])
print('A120: ', clf.coef_[1])    
print('A70: ', clf.coef_[2])
print('A84: ', clf.coef_[3])
print('A81: ', clf.coef_[4])
print('A89: ', clf.coef_[5])
print('A101: ', clf.coef_[6])
print('A102: ', clf.coef_[7])
print('A105: ', clf.coef_[8])
```

Hopefully you can see that I want to index my X feature values and the coefficients so that I can refer to what each coefficient is, specifically. I feel like their is definitely a simpler way to get this result than the way I'm doing it now. Thank you!

Comment: Usually people use `df.values` to get an array version of the `df`, rather than `np.array(df)`.

Comment: I'm mainly referencing sentdex on YouTube right now, so I basically used his ideas as some of the functions were new to me, but I will be sure to implement this on some more personal projects like this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a list of column numbers, i.e.

```
col_numbers = [71, 120, 70, 84, 81, 89, 101, 102, 105]
```

then create a list out of them,

```
col_names = ['A{}: '.format(num) for num in col_numbers]
```

grab those specific columns from the dataframe,

```
df = df[col_names]
```

and use a for loop to print,

```
for i in range(len(col_names)):
    print(col_names[i], clf.coef_[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the order of your `DataFrame` you can do this pretty efficiently with a simple zip:

```
for x in zip(df.columns, clf_coeff):
    print(x[0], x[1])
```

---

### Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A71: ', 'A120: ', 'A70: ', 'A84: ', 'A81: ', 
                             'A89: ', 'A101: ', 'A102: ', 'A105: ', 'CR'])
clf_coeff = np.arange(0, 9, 1)

for x in zip(df.columns, clf_coeff):
    print(x[0], x[1])
```

Output:

```
A71:  0
A120:  1
A70:  2
A84:  3
A81:  4
A89:  5
A101:  6
A102:  7
A105:  8
```

Here the key is that though df.columns is longer than clf_coeff, zip will stop once one of end of the shorter array is reached, meaning it doesn't matter that `'CR'` is at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate the answer, but clf.coef_ is one of the built in functions on sklearn, so I went with bstrauch24's answer, but all these tips are super helpful in keeping my learning curve on track, so I'm definitely going to implement your advice on a personal project!

Comment: Yes, but it is an array, which you can index, so you should be able to apply this?